# Installing modules via pip in cmd, Windows 10, Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pip, python-module

I need to be able to pip install Python modules, and I'm new to computer programming. I keep getting the same invalid syntax errors.

Here's the exact error. Unfortunately it's not much to go on:

```
>>> pip install beautifulsoup4
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install beautifulsoup4
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's what I've read and tried:

1. Ran cmd as administrator.
2. All pip attempts have been in the command line, not the Python shell or editor.
3. Every permutation I can find in the textbook, online, or youtube: "`pip install requests`", "`pip -m install requests`", "`C:/...Scripts> pip install requests`", and several others.
4. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling a different version of Python, both 32- and 64-bit. (Windows is 64-bit, but 32-bit has better compatibility, I hear.)
5. Hit the docs hard for install, pathway (it's correct and the command line recognizes Python 3.5.2) and pip.

I'm losing it here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, save one. Do not tell me that I need to be running the install script in the command line, not in Python. I have never ran it in Python.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you include the *actual exact error* that you're getting. Now it's 100% guessing.

Comment: I have to tell you what you don't want to hear. You need to run pip from the cmd shell command line. You're trying to run it inside of Python's REPL.